# hp-probe find printer network or alternative

Tags: networking, printing

I am working in a environment where we have different network. One of them are used for printers (192.168.x.x) and 1 for wireless network (10.1.x.x). I need to add a printer HP C3505 (192.168.x.x) on my Ubuntu (10.1.x.x).

I am using hp-probe to find out what is the IP but it cannot find it, i am guessing because I am not on the same network.

I use:

```
hp-probe -bnet
```

Is there another tool i can use to find the IP of the printer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution will be to scan the network and find printers. Yes hp-probe (as far as I know, is using the current network even with the -m option it never worked for me.)

A (slow) way to find them is using `nmap`:

for example:

```
sudo nmap -sP 10.16.1.1-255
```

The last part will scan from 1 to 255. This might take time.

Then you can check the type by using `-O` to find out what type of host the IP is.

```
sudo nmap -O 10.16.1.100
```

Will output:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-01-30 15:23 EST
Nmap scan report for 10.16.1.100
Host is up (0.00032s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
23/tcp    open  telnet
80/tcp    open  http
280/tcp   open  http-mgmt
443/tcp   open  https
515/tcp   open  printer
631/tcp   open  ipp
9100/tcp  open  jetdirect
14000/tcp open  unknown
Device type: printer <-----------------------------------------------------
Running: HP embedded
OS details: HP LaserJet 2420, P3005, CP4005, or P4014 printer <------------
Network Distance: 1 hop

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.69 seconds
```

Then you can add using the printer tool.